# Solution of the poisson equation on a rectangle

Tags: numerical-methods, poissons-equation

I have the solution $u(x,y) = \sin(k\pi x) \sinh(k\pi (1-y))$ of the poisson problem

$
\nabla^2u(x,y) = 0 \\
u(x, 1) = u(1, y) = u(0, y) = 0 \\
u(x, 0) = \sin(k\pi x)
$

Now I thought when my domain is not square, the solution of the problem

$
\nabla^2u(x,y) = 0 \\
u(x, y_{max}) = u(1, y) = u(0, y) = 0 \\
u(x, 0) = \sin(k\pi x)
$

would be scaled by the y-range: $u(x,y) = \sin(k\pi x) \sinh(k\pi (y_{max}-y)$

but this does not match my numeric solution.

I wonder if the solution is incorrect, if my numeric solution is wrong or if the solution is no longer unique and the numeric solution is another function than the analytic one.

Comment: To me, if a scale is changed, then it should be $u(x,y) = \sin( \frac{ k\pi}{y_{max}} x    ) \sinh(k\pi (1- \frac{y}{y_{max}}))$ but this dose not satisfy the boundary condition. Laplace operator is not preserved by coodinate transformations. If  a coodinate system is changed, then the solution no longer satisfy the Laplace equation in a new coordinate system.

Comment: For example, Let $u(x,y)$ satisfy $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial }{\partial y})^2 =0$, and  let $(x',y')=(x'(x,y),y'(x,y))$ be new coordinates, then, generally speaking, $u(x(x',y'),y(x',y'))$ dose not satisfy  $(\frac{\partial }{\partial x'})^2+(\frac{\partial }{\partial y'})^2 =0$.

Comment: @CamfordOxbridge Thank you. I think I can satisfy the boundary conditions by just setting the new $u(x, y)$ on the boundary or is this for some reason a bad idea? When you make your comment an answer I can accept it.